# Force Spark to compute in parrallel

Tags: json, apache-spark

With Spark 1.6.2, reading a gzip compressed JSON file from a normal file-system:

```
val df = sqlContext
    .read
    .json("file:///data/blablacar/transactions.json.gz")
    .count()
```

Will use a single task on a single worker.

But if I save the file:

```
sc.textFile("file:///data/blablacar/transactions.json.gz")
    .saveAsTextFile("file:///user/blablacar/transactions")

sqlContext.read.json("file:///user/blablacar/transactions")
.count()
```

Will execute the first job on a single task, but the JSON decoding on several (which is good!).

Why Spark didn't unzip the file in memory and distribute the JSON decoding in several task in the 1st case?

Answer (score 2):

> Why Spark didn't unzip the file in memory and distribute the JSON decoding in several task in the 1st case?

Because you gzip compression is not splittable, therefore file has to be loaded as whole one a single machine. If you want parallel reads:

- Don't use gzip at all, or
- Use gzip compression on smaller files comparable to split size, or
- Unpack files yourself before you pass them to Spark.

Comment: Yes sure, it's not splittable, but the most work is about JSON decoding not uncompressing the file.

Comment: I have no choice on file format, I am using Parquet usually, but here, I have X To of files like this :/

Answer (score 0):

Calling `.repartition(8)` did the trick!

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("file:///data/blablacar/transactions.json.gz")
    .repartition(8)

sqlContext.read.json(rdd)
.count()
```

[image]